# Is there any way to determine whether a web page follows REST or SOAP architecture?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Basically I want to know whether a web page is a RESTful API or a SOAP

Answer (score -1):

you may want to hit the Developer Tools and look at the Network. At the requests, you can normally see a SOAP-Envelope or a REST Method.

Regards,
Leni

Comment: Well, do you mean from the "page source" option ? I have tried that option but unable to trace whether its a SOAP or a REST client. Need more clarity on your answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you want to do? When you open the Developer Tools you've got the "Network Tab" where you can see the communication happening on the webpage. When you inspect the Requests you can normally see the Method (POST, GET ... for RESTful) in the Headers.